# Unable to create new features in Machine learning

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset. I am using pandas dataframe and named it `df`.
The dataset has 50,000 rows - here are the first 5:.

```
Name_Restaurant              cuisines_available             Average cost

Food Heart                     Japnese, chinese                60$
Spice n Hungary             Indian, American, mexican          42$
kfc, Lukestreet                 Thai, Japnese                  29$
Brown bread shop                American                       11$
kfc, Hypert mall               Thai, Japnese                   40$
```

1. I want to create column which contains the no. of cuisines available
   I am trying code

   ```
   df['no._of_cuisines_available']=df['cuisines_available'].str.len()
   ```

   Then instead of showing the no. of cuisines, it is showing the sum of charecters.
   For example - for first row the o/p should be 2 , but its showing 17.
2. I need a new column that contain number of stores for each restaurant. example -
   here kfc has 2 stores kfc, lukestreet and kfc, hypert mall. I have completely
   no idea how to code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i)

```
df['cuisines_available'].str.split(',').apply(len)
```

ii)

```
df['Name_Restaurant'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt().['value'].str.strip().value_counts()
```

What ii) does: split columns at ',' and store all strings thus generated in an individual column. Then use melt to make one big column, strip away spaces etc. and count individual entries.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer for question 2 also

Comment: I am getting the nan  while trying this second code

Comment: @Ashu value_counts has dropna as default argument, so you should not see the nans in th resulting table.